# Node.js 14 optional chaining and spread operator in array

Tags: javascript, optional-chaining

Here is a snippet of my code

```
const data = [ ...prev, ...resp.data ]
```

This crashes if `resp.data` is not defined. With the new chaining operator syntax I have found following solution how to handle the case that `resp.data` is `undefined`.

```
const data = [ ...prev, ...( resp?.data || [] ) ]
```

It works fine. I just wonder if there is some shorter syntax.

Comment: Single character shorter: `const data = [].concat( prev, resp?.data || [] )` but it doesn't use spread syntax any more.

Comment: Oops, turns out I cannot count. The above is *longer* but has less spaces. `prev.concat( resp?.data || [] )` is two characters shorter if we ignore the whitespaces.